# how can I generate suface mesh non-uniformly using CGAL?

Tags: mesh, cgal, geometry-surface

I want to generate surface mesh(3d triangle mesh) non-uniformly,How can I do it with CGAL?

when I use Polygon Mesh Processing package,I got result like this:
all the triangle have almostly same size

[image]

But I want to generate triangle mesh like this:
different area have different triangle size, I mean it is adaptively.
It also called anisotropic mesh

[image]

Thanks very much!

Comment: is there anybody know? please tell me ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function you used in the [Polygon Mesh Processing](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/) package is named [`isotropic_remeshing()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__meshing__grp.html). Isotropic basically means that all triangles will have the same size. If you want to have more control on the size of the triangles you need to use another method like those in the [`Mesh_3` package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/).
You can have a look at [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2remesh_polyhedral_surface_8cpp-example.html).